# Why the values from the file are not being stored in the class attributes?

Tags: java, file, file-handling

I am trying to write a code, that reads from a file that has products of apple listed in it. I also have two classes that store the data from the file in array of the objects from those files.

But whenever I try to get values from the array of those objects, it always remains null.

I think something is going wrong with reading those values from file, but I can't spot which. Also, there's no debugger at my disposal currently.

This is the code which I am using to read file and store its values in classes.

```java
Scanner fScanner=null;
        FileWriter fw = null;


        try {
            fScanner = new Scanner(new File("apple.txt"));
        } 
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        }

        while(fScanner.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = fScanner.nextLine();
            Scanner lineScanner = new Scanner(line);

            if(lineScanner.next().equals("IPHONE")) 
                countIphone++;

            else if(lineScanner.next().equals("IPAD"))
                countIpad++;
        }

            Iphone[] iphone = new Iphone[countIphone];
            Ipad[] ipad = new Ipad[countIpad];

        while(fScanner.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = fScanner.nextLine();
            Scanner lineScanner = new Scanner(line);

            if(lineScanner.next().equals("IPHONE")) {
                for(int i=0;i<countIphone;i++) {
                    iphone[i].setModel("IPHONE"+lineScanner.useDelimiter(",").next());
                    iphone[i].setScreenSize(lineScanner.useDelimiter(",").next());
                    iphone[i].setProcessor(lineScanner.useDelimiter(",").next());
                    iphone[i].setSimType(lineScanner.useDelimiter(",").next());
                    iphone[i].setColor(lineScanner.useDelimiter(",").next());
                    iphone[i].setROM(lineScanner.useDelimiter(",").next());
                    iphone[i].setIs3DTouch(lineScanner.useDelimiter(",").next());
                    iphone[i].setPrice(lineScanner.useDelimiter(",").next());
                }
            }


            else if(lineScanner.next().equals("IPAD")) {
                for(int i=0;i<countIpad;i++) {
                    ipad[i].setModel("IPAD"+lineScanner.useDelimiter(",").next());
                    ipad[i].setScreenSize(lineScanner.useDelimiter(",").next());
                    ipad[i].setProcessor(lineScanner.useDelimiter(",").next());
                    ipad[i].setIsWifi(lineScanner.useDelimiter(",").next());
                    ipad[i].setColor(lineScanner.useDelimiter(",").next());
                    ipad[i].setMemory(lineScanner.useDelimiter(",").next());
                    ipad[i].setPrice(lineScanner.useDelimiter(",").next());
                }
            }

        }
```

The file looks like this:

```text
IPHONE 7, 4.7, A10, GSM, JET BLACK, 32GB, TRUE, 700
IPAD AIR 2, 9.7, A8, TRUE, SILVER, 64GB, 400
IPHONE SE, 4, A9, CDMA, SILVER, 16GB, FALSE, 490
IPAD PRO, 9.7, A9, TRUE, SPACE GREY, 32GB, 650
IPHONE X, 7, A11, LTE, BLACK, 128GB, TRUE, 999
IPAD PRO X, 12, A12, TRUE, SPACE GREY, 256GB, 700
```

Comment: Sorry bit in this code i don't see initializate the variables countIpad and countIphone...

Comment: @Ferdinando thank you for trying to understand the problem. I have initialised and declared those variables, but I have not put in this this code, I have only given the part regarding the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@dasblinkenlight has pointed out the reason why `iphone` and `ipad` are empty. But there are still some things wrong:

- While  iterating `for(int i=0;i<countIphone;i++) { ... }` `iphone[i]` is `null`. You never assigned `iphone[i] = new Iphone();`. Thus trying to invoke a method like `iphone[i].setModel(...)` will throw a `NullPointerException`. The same applies to the iteration over `ipad`.
- Something less obvious is that calling `new Scanner(new File("apple.txt"))` you're opening a resource. It's not closed in the code. If you want still use `Scanner` work with the [try-resource-statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html).

I would like to suggest another design and using [nio-API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/nio/file/package-summary.html) and [stream-API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html).

At first I define an enum for the known devices:

```
  public enum Device {
    IPHONE, IPAD;

    public static Device byName(String name) {
      return Arrays.stream(values())
        .filter(d -> name.startsWith(d.toString()))
        .findAny()
        .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException(String.format("Unknown device name %s", name)));
    }
  }
```

The method `Device.byName` returns for the first word in a line from *apple.txt* the corresponding `Device`.

For each device I define a `Function` which acts as a factory. It takes a split line (split by `", "`) from *apple.txt* and returns the appropriate instance.

```
  private static Function<String[], Iphone> toIphone() {
    return line -> {
      Iphone iphone = new Iphone();
      iphone.setModel(Device.IPHONE.toString() + line[0].split(" ")[1]);
      iphone.setScreenSize(line[1]);
      iphone.setProcessor(line[2]);
      iphone.setSimType(line[3]);
      iphone.setColor(line[4]);
      iphone.setROM(line[5]);
      iphone.setIs3DTouch(line[6]);
      iphone.setPrice(line[7]);
      return iphone;
    };
  }

  private static Function<String[], Ipad> toIpad() {
    return line -> {
      Ipad ipad = new Ipad();
      ipad.setModel(Device.IPAD.toString() + line[0].split(" ")[1]);
      ipad.setScreenSize(line[1]);
      ipad.setProcessor(line[2]);
      ipad.setIsWifi(line[3]);
      ipad.setColor(line[4]);
      ipad.setMemory(line[5]);
      ipad.setPrice(line[6]);
      return ipad;
    };
  }
```

To decide which method to call I define a method which takes a split line representing a device from *apple.txt*. It calls `Device.byName` passing in the first element of the split line.

```
  private static Device classify(String[] device) {
    return Device.byName(device[0]);
  }
```

Now we can use the above code to do the file processing like that:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Map<Device, List<String[]>> devices = Files
      .lines(new File("./apple.txt").toPath())
      .map(l -> l.split(", "))
      .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Example::classify));

    Iphone[] iphones = devices.get(Device.IPHONE).stream()
      .map(toIphone())
      .toArray(Iphone[]::new);
    Ipad[] ipads = devices.get(Device.IPAD).stream()
      .map(toIpad())
      .toArray(Ipad[]::new);
  }
```

Using `Files.lines` we don't need to worry about closing the read `File`.
By calling `Collectors.groupingBy(Example::classify)` we receive a `Map` from the `Stream` which has instances of `Device` as keys. For a `Devices` it returns a `List` with all corresponding instances.

Comment: This was one of the most informative answers I have ever come across. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm goes through the file twice:

- First `while(fScanner.hasNextLine())` loop counts iphones and ipads in the file
- Second `while(fScanner.hasNextLine())` loop reads the actual data

The problem is that once the first loop is over, all the input has been consumed.

You can fix this problem by closing and re-opening the scanner. However, your code has other problems - `for` loops inside the conditionals assume that all iphones and all ipads are in the file together, while that is not so.

You you fix this by combining the scanning loops and using a resizable container for iphones and ipads:

```
List<Iphone> iphones = new ArrayList<>();
List<Ipad> ipads = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: Ah, the scanner opening and closing, part, I understood, and I have rectified it. But I didn't get what you are saying about the other part. For loop and ahead, part. Can you please tell it more specifically.

Comment: @Manhar When your second loop sees the first line with iphone, it gets into the `for` loop that tries to read all `countIphone` iphones (in your case that's 3) assuming that all iphones go together in the file. However, only the first pass through the `for` loop succeeds, because you run into next line, which is for an ipad.